# How do I initialize a primitive, and add to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to initialize a variable as a float and then add to it in a times loop. Here's my code:

```
amt = 0.0

5.times do
  amt = amt + ("%.2f" % (item.price * 0.05)) 
end
```

Here's the error:

```
String can't be coerced into Float
```

EDIT:

I've changed the `1.times do`. I had adapted my code so that it would be more readable, the `1.times` wasn't in my actual code.

Comment: It's probably because you are trying to mod (item.price*0.05) by "%.2f", what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm assuming its some sort of sprintf style thing.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh Well, wouldn't wanna do it twice.

Comment: There are no primitives. *(Only Zuul.)*

Comment: @JessePollak Not exactly; try `"%.2f" % 42` in `irb`.

Comment: Woah, didn't realize that. Where can I learn more?

Comment: @JessePollak The [String#% docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/%25), and the [Kernel#sprintf docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, try not to use floats for money - what you'll need to do in this case is use BigDecimal - floating point math is not accurate.

To use BigDecimal, require 'bigdecimal' in your application.rb

Then, what you want is:

```
amt = BigDecimal.new("0")

1.times do
  price = BigDecimal.new(item.price.to_s)
  factor = BigDecimal.new("0.05")
  amt += (price * factor).round(2)
end

amt
```

Comment: Or treat every thing as cents and divide by 100 to get the dollar amount.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sorry everyone. I am new to Ruby so I didn't know that this was the problem, but the "%.2f" was causing the problem. (Although irrelevant to this question, what this does is convert the amount into two decimal precision.) Stupid mistake!

Comment: But why not just add it? There's no reason to convert it to anything. And was the 1.times thing leftover from something? It's a little weird.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was simplifying the problem statement. The actual loop has some more complicated Rails syntax -- I wanted to simplify it so that those with just Ruby knowledge would be able to answer.

Comment: Hmm, I might have just left the loop out all together then, since it's not really part of the question :) But it doesn't convert to "two decimal precision", it converts it to a string, co-incidentally doing some formatting along the way, causing the problem.